# PHP: Copy files using alternate credentials?

Tags: php

Using PHP's `copy()` function, is it possible to perform the copy using alternate credentials (a different user account)?

Currently, I’m copying files from one Windows directory to another Windows Server and was wondering if I could do this using another account than I am currently using.

Comment: Are you using PHP CLI? Can you show your current script?

Comment: @MikeBrant no, I'm not

Comment: Your PHP server (I assume IIS as you're using Windows) is running under a special account called `IUSR`. I'm not sure it's possible for PHP to run under another person's account or even emulate this action somehow.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot directly manipulate the user credentials like that.  Instead you will have to spawn a new process to do the copying under a different user's login.

On Linux or Mac OS X you could arrange it with the `sudo` command, as long as you properly set up the `sudoers` file (using `visudo`).

On Windows you can use the `runas` command to execute a script as a different user.

Answer (score 3):

`runas` is the only way that I know of.  Run the command using `exec()` and use the Windows `copy` command:

```
exec("cmd /C echo password | runas /user:username copy \\path\\to\\file \\\\servername\\path\\");
```

There are other switches for `runas`.  You might look at the `/no profile` and `/netonly`.

Comment: sorry to drag this up from 2014, but i have a similar issue.
i'm trying to copy a file from another server on to the IIS webserver.
both servers are windows.

will this command work if the source is on another server and i want to copy it to the webserver?

Comment: @chenks: If the username has permissions to the other server then it should. Write up a detailed question and you will get some answers.

Comment: i would, but i'm currently not allowed to ask any new questions due to the system not letting me.